# What should I conclude from this - A gay man

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, american-english

I fell in love with this course, from an American university, and wanted to enroll in it.

But, when I went to the professor's page, to request him to let me in,
 I saw this - `I am a gay man and use he/him pronouns`.

I do not have any problem, I just want to ask what does being a 'gay' imply here.

A 'gay' man doesn't need to use she/her ?
     OR
Is the author telling that he is cheerful ?

PS - I am a student, and I have nothing against straight/LGBTQ/Other living beings.

Comment: It means he is homosexual.  Within the LGBTQ community (and without) there is a disagreement as to which personal pronouns to use when referring to someone of unknown gender.  He apparently uses he/him (which used to be the "default" for heterosexual people, before it became an issue).

Comment: Gender and sexual orientation are separate things.  He's giving you two effectively unrelated pieces of information.  He's a man attracted to men, and the pronouns he prefers you use for him are "he" and "him".

Comment: @HotLicks One **al­ways** uses *he/his/him* for hu­man males in English; their af­fec­tional ori­en­ta­tion has no bear­ing on this even in our post­modern world.

Comment: @tchrist - I said "to use when referring to someone of unknown gender".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I found the page you are referring to and took a look. I believe that this also could have be written as "I am a gay man. I use he/him pronouns." I think he is just providing two pieces of information that might be helpful in communicating with him, and that they are not necessarily related. I do not think he is referring to his general mood or that he is cheerful.

Comment: Thank you. I must admit that I wouldn't have understood what the author really wanted to convey, on my own. Thanks for the websites like stackexchange. Happy new year!